# How to split columns and shift column values using R

Tags: r, csv, data-cleaning

I have extracted a small amount of the csv file here.http://www.sharecsv.com/s/8ccf9c932f3cbf7def2a4fd4ea30c6f7/test.csv

```
Th  02:56:21    M14     N60321J     IVL     13  OCC     0   LQ  -112    BQ  0   EB0     LIT     1111
Th  02:56:21    M14     N60341D     IVL     14  OCC     0   LQ  -72     BQ  0   EB0     LIT     1111
Th  02:56:21    M14     N60421K     IVL     115     OCC     0   LQ  0   BQ  0   EB0     LIT     0
Th  02:56:21    M14     N60431E     IVL     12  OCC     0   LQ-3361     BQ  0   EB0     LIT     1111    
Th  02:56:21    M14     N60431E     IVL     13  OCC     0   LQ-3417     BQ  0   EB0     LIT     1111
```

How can i use R to split column "V13" into 2 columns. Take the first row for example the First column represting the text "EB" and second column representing the number "0".

Additionally the formatting of the 4th and 5th row change slightly. Everything should be shifted over by one column. because the column "V9" should be split into 2 columns the first representing "LQ" and the second representing the number "-3361"

This is a small amount of dataset and im not sure if the text will always be LQ and EB in the larger file.

Answer (score 0):

For splitting column V13, you can use the `substring` function:

```
dataframe$V13a = substring(dataframe$V13,1,2) #For first 2 characters
dataframe$V13b = substring(dataframe$V13,3)  #For characters 3 onwards
```

Shifting cells over is a harder problem to solve in R, but you can do it with the `readLines()` function and some preprocessing before feeding it into a data.frame:

```
lines <- readLines("path_to_file.csv")
lines <- strsplit(lines, "(\\s+|(?<=[A-Z])(?=-))", perl=TRUE)
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lines))
```

The strsplit splits each line based on the regular expression, either one or more spaces, or if a character is followed by `-`. This is then bound together into a matrix using rbind, through do.call (applying the rbind function to all items in the list of lines), and then converted to a data.frame.